# What is the open question/conjecture about the first $\omega$ many measurable and strongly compact cardinals?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

I seem to remember an open problem or conjecture about the first $\omega$ many measurable cardinals and the first $\omega$ many strongly compact cardinals, but I cannot find it.  Does anyone know the exact statement or any progress?

Comment: One major open question is: can the first $\omega$ many measurable cardinals be the first $\omega$ many strongly compact cardinals?

Comment: Thanks Mohammed, just to be clear we are wondering if there is a forcing extension where this is possible?  Since it does not have to be true.  Has there been any progress lately?

Comment: The question is about the consistency of the statement. It is quite open. The best result that I know is due to Kimchi and Magidor that for any finite $n$, it is consistent that the first $n$ strongly compact cardinals can  be the first $n$ measurable cardinals.  See [On the indestructibility aspects of identity
 crisis](http://www.grigorsargis.net/identitycrisis.pdf) and the references there.

Comment: @MohammadGolshani thank you very much